# ruby YAML parse bug with number

Tags: ruby, yaml

I have encountered what appears to be a bug with the YAML parser. Take this simple yaml file for example:

```
new account:
  - FLEETBOSTON
  - 011001742
```

If you parse it using this ruby line of code:

```
INPUT_DATA = YAML.load_file("test.yml")
```

Then I get this back:

```
{"new account"=>["FLEETBOSTON", 2360290]}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Because I'm pretty sure this is never supposed to happen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is supposed to happen. Numbers starting with `0` are in octal notation. Unless the next character is `x`, in which case they're hexadecimal.

```
07 == 7
010 == 8
011 == 9

0x9 == 9
0xA == 10
0xF == 15
0x10 == 16
0x11 == 17
```

Go into `irb` and just type in `011001742`.

```
1.9.2-p290 :001 > 011001742
 => 2360290
```

PEBKAC. :)

Your number is a number, so it's treated as a number. If you want to make it explictly a string, enclose it into quotes, so YAML will not try to make it a number.

```
new account:
  - FLEETBOSTON
  - '011001742'
```

Comment: The use of `=` instead of `==` with code formatting might be interpreted wrongly as assignment (which it cannot be, since numbers are not lvalues).

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: Yeah, wasn't meant to be code, just an illustration; but I'll change it.

Comment: Yea I know it was meant to be mathematical equality rather than assignment, it just looks odd and didn't want others to be confused. If only this were a Prolog question… `;)`.

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna go off on a limb here... octal notation sucks. Just saying :)